# How do I format a string based on certain delimeters in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, formatting

Let a = "cat AND mouse AND hen OR pig AND cow OR horse"

Expected output ="((cat AND mouse AND hen) OR (pig AND cow) OR horse)"

All the consecutive AND should be inside a bracket.

Comment: Hint: This can be done by using split and join operations on string.

Comment: Yes I did it that way, but I'm unable to derive correct logic when more than one AND is involved.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = "cat AND mouse AND hen OR pig AND cow OR horse"
var orSplits = 
a = "("+a.replace(/ OR /g, ") OR (")+")";
console.log(a)
```